# Flash dynamic images disappear on IE browsers when scrollbar appears

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, scrollbar, window-resize

I have a swf thats loading external images to it.

In all IE browsers, when i resize the browser window and the scroll bar appears, over half the images in my flash swf disappear.
When i resize and the scrollbar disappears then the all flash images appear.

Oddly enough this only happens when flash is loading over 38 images.

Any ideas?

Comment: Removing "margin:0 auto" from all parent divs fixes the issue in IE9 and 8 which means nothing in my site is centered...
IE7 is still messed up...

Comment: Making the div the first element in the body with an absolute position helped. Keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the Divs to absolute removed this issue from all IE browsers. Strange, still, the flash elements reacting like that but there an answer for anyone who's having a similar problem.